# Any mode for Modula 2?

Tags: major-mode

I'm (after a hiatus of some 30 years) dabbling again in Modula 2 (yes, too much time cooped up). But neither ELPA nor MELPA knows anything about a mode for GNU Emacs. This site seems not to mention the language either. Any hints? Perhaps (ab)use a mode for a similar language, like Pascal?

Comment: Emacs comes with a Modula-2 mode built-in. Perhaps try that?

Comment: @NickD, I looked all over and was surprised by that (undocumented?) mode when editing a random Modula 2 source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my surprise, after looking all over without getting any leads (and thus asking here), I just set to edit some Modula 2 source code. I was prepared to use plain text mode or a mode for say Pascal (somewhat similar). To my surprise, emacs went into Modula 2 mode.

So the short answer is: Modula 2 mode is build into the standard distribution.